# Use of unassigned local variable 'flag'

Tags: c#

Can't figure out why I'm getting an error on the **flag**. Any help will be appreciated!
goal is to generate a 40 character using the below specified characters.

public static string udidGen()
        {

```
        bool flag;
        string s1 = "";
        string[] sArr2 = new string[] {
                                        "0", 
                                        "1", 
                                        "2", 
                                        "3", 
                                        "4", 
                                        "5", 
                                        "6", 
                                        "7", 
                                        "8", 
                                        "9", 
                                        "a", 
                                        "b", 
                                        "c", 
                                        "d", 
                                        "e", 
                                        "f" };
        string[] sArr1 = sArr2;
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = 0;

        while (**flag**)
        {
            s1 += sArr1[random.Next(0, 15)];
            i++;
            flag = i < 40;
        }
        return s1;
    }
```

Comment: Aside from the coding style issues (appending a string, unclear loop, unnecessary array copying, etc.), there is one other thing that's broken here - for random.Next, the 2nd argument should be 16, not 15. random.Next(0, 16) will give you a random number between 0 and 15 (don't ask me why they did it that way).

Comment: Also, your random variable should really be declared as a static field and instantiated only once (or instantiated with a different seed every time).  This will ensure that each time it calls "Next" it will give you something random, and not the same values every time.  To demonstrate, try making this call 10 times in a row - you'll likely get the same result several times in a row.

Answer (score 2):

You are using flag without assigning it a value. Change the first line to:

bool flag = true;

Even better, get rid of 'flag' altogether and replace the while loop with a for loop

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
...
}

Answer (score 0):

The first time the `while` executes, `flag` has never been set to anything yet -- be thankful to the compiler/runtime for pointing out to you what could otherwise have proved to be a very hard-to-catch bug!

You should initialize the variable to `true` before the loop, ideally in the declaration itself:

```
bool flag = true;
```

Comment: I don't understand this, bool is a value type and so has a default value of false? Just had same error and it confused me

Comment: @DavidB, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx, "using uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed" -- default values have nothing to do with the case.

Comment: Top one - I found that article yesterday. Was surprised I had never noticed before

Answer (score 0):

`flag` variable has not been initialised, which is not allowed by C# compiler. In this case you want to make it true so you go into the loop at least once.

```
bool flag = true;
```